Why does the heat conductance increase with the interlayer spacing
I am studying the heat conductance of the Al2O3/Bilayer Graphene/Al2O3 hetero-system. What I found is that when I increase the interlayer spacing between bilayer graphene and that between graphene and Al2O3, the heat conductance also increases. For example, the heat conductance of this system is 12.5481 W/(mK) when the spacing is 2.5 angstroms; while, the heat conductance is 22.8372 W/(mK) when the spacing is 3.4 angstroms; then, the conductance reaches 24.2143 W/(m*K) when the spacing is 6.4 angstroms.
What I suppose to obtain is that the heat conductance decreases when the spacing increases. I do not understand why the conductance increases with the spacing.
Would anyone please give me some explanations/comments/hints?
Thank you very much in advance.
